# Solving magic square results in incorrect answer

Tags: magic-square

I'm trying to help my daughter with [her homework](https://corbettmaths.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/negatives-multiplication-and-division.pdf).  I'm not looking for an answer, but the process.

She has been asked to solve this:

```
[ [   ?,  36,   ? ]
  [   9,   6,   4 ]
  [ -12,   ?,   ? ] ]
```

My approach was to substitute letters for the missing values:

```
[ [   A,  36,   B ]
  [   9,   6,   4 ]
  [ -12,   C,   D ] ]
```

Then I could solve for the unknowns:

```
  9 +  6 + 4 = 19
  A + 36 + B = 19
-12 +  C + D = 19
...
```

Solving the equations resulted in most of the rows, columns and diagonals adding up to 19 - however, not all did.  I ended up with:

```
A = -42
B = 25
C = -24
D = 55
```

I'm not clear where I'm going wrong.

---

My Math knowledge is very poor, simple clear answers will be preferred over complex answers.

Comment: Did the problem state it was a magic square?

Comment: Yes - source: https://corbettmaths.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/negatives-multiplication-and-division.pdf

Comment: Note that the referenced file says that the *product*, not the *sum*, should be constant.

Comment: Ah!  So you need to make sure that the *product* is the same in each row, column, and diagonal, rather than the *sum*! I;m sure your daughter can do this. :)

Comment: Is there a way to mark a question as answered when the answer is only from comments?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee I don't know ... I've had the same thought many times myself; it would be nice to be able to get questions out of the 'Unanswered' queue!

Comment: just post your point in the answers box and have the asker accept it.

Comment: Here's a [link to a discussion of this issue on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments)

Comment: It takes two days before I can accept my own answer.  Happy to accept someone else's answer.

Comment: I think it's possible to mark the answer as a "community answer" but I'm not sure what the etiquette is on that ... I guess it doesn't really matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comments, the *products*, not the sums, of the rows and columns should be the same.

Apart from that, I think it's a bit cumbersome to introduce so many variables and equations. Just solve the values one at a time. For example, the second row has product $4\cdot6\cdot9$, so the missing entry in the second column must be $1$, etc.